# Show div from ASP.NET code

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have this div which is hidden originally:

```
<div id="loading" class="window">
    <img src="../Images/test.gif" />
</div>
```

How can I call this div to be shown while a thread is running

```
Thread thread = new Thread(test);
thread.Start()

private void test()
{
//code to see div
}
```

edit: I want the div to appear on top of the page so user wont be able to click on anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Remove the display:none from the class and replace the div with an ASP.NET control:

```
<asp:Panel ID="loading" CssClass="window" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <img src="../Images/test.gif" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Then:

```
private void test()
{
    loading.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want a div not a panel to be visible on top of everything so that user cannot click on anything else

Comment: A Panel will render as a div. There's absolutely no difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

add `runat="server"` attribute inside div. by this div will work like server control and you can access this in code behind and add attribute

```
private void test()
{
    loading.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `runat="server"` to your div, then access it in the code like: `this.yourDivId` and you can show it like `this.yourDivId.Visible = true;`